# Issue with __range function in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

What I need to do is filter all the sales objects from a particular zone and region and within a date range. So, I used the __range function in the query something like this

```
start = start_date.strftime('%d-%b-%y')
end = end_date.strftime('%d-%b-%y')
Sales.objects.filter(zone_code=zone_code_, region_code=region_code_, sales_date__range(start,end))
```

All my dates are stored as characters in my models, so I changed the input dates to that format using strftime(). 
But this query is giving me objects beyond the specified range, and sometimes a null set.

Answer (score 4):

[`__range`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#range) is not a function and can't be called. It is a [Field lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups) that needs to be appended to the model field name and passed as the key of a keyword argument to e.g. the `filter()` function. The value must be a tuple with the start and end date of the range:

```
Sales.objects.filter(
    zone_code=zone_code_, 
    region_code=region_code_, 
    sales_date__range=(start, end),  # pass the tuple as a kwarg
)
```

Note the `=` before the `(start, end)` tuple!

You do not need to convert `start` or `end` to strings.

Comment: I have stored the dates in my models as strings, so if i don't convert my start and end to strings I am getting an empty set

Comment: @ShashankJ Why do you store dates as strings?

Comment: I had to populate the database from a csv file, so I just copied the data from csv file and stored as characters instead of datetime objects.

Comment: @ShashankJ But that means the database will compare them using the alphabetical order of the characters in the date string. This is not what you want. You should migrate your data to a `DateTimeField`.

Comment: @trixn Hi, While searching for a record bet two dates (`from_date` and `to_date`), I am getting error `NameError: name 'from_date' is not defined` although correct field name is included in the query. To check that, if I change the field name in the query to something else, an error is thrown: `Cannot resolve keyword 'ref_date' into field. Choices are:`. ** And among the list of fields thrown at me lies the `from_date` field. `ref_date` is the date being checked for the date range. I had checked the date types and they are correct. Can you point me to something to correct the anomaly?

Comment: @user12379095 A [`NameError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#NameError) is a python error that is raised when a local or global name is not found. I guess you meant to use `from_date` as a string literal `'from_date'` or as a key of a keyword argument to reference the field but you actually used it as if it was a variable `from_date` without the sourounding `' '`.

Comment: @trixn Actually I have tried to include the ' ' **quotes** but raises the error `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword ref_date' into field. Choices are: from_date, ...`, the same as with changing the field name to something that is not there (as explained before). My query goes like: `PriceItems.objects.filter(ref_date__range=(from_date, to_date)).select_related('price_header').filter(price_header__material=myMaterial).get(price_header__price_point=myPricingPt).item_price`. As you can see fields `from_date` and `to_date` are part of the model `PriceItems`. Any idea?

Comment: @user12379095 To reference fields of the model on the right side of the filter keyword argument you need to wrap them into `models.F()`. Also see [Filters can reference fields on the model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model). So it must be `PriceItems.objects.filter(ref_date__range=(models.F('from_date'), models.F('to_date'))` assuming that `from_date` and `to_date` are fields of the `PriceItem` model. Otherwise the items in the tuple need to be `datetime` instances, not strings.

Comment: Still gettin `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'ref_date' into field. Choices are: from_date, ...`. If I remove the **quotes** from the date fields (yeah, they are part of the model **PriceItems**), I am getting **error** `NameError: name 'from_date' is not defined`. Also I had to import "modes"  : `from django.db import models` as otherwise I was getting error: `NameError: name 'models' is not defined`.

Comment: @user12379095 Is `ref_date` a field of the model?

Comment: No, this is a date variable which is passed a date (at runtime) for carrying out a check. Price records (i.e. **item_price**) are stored with validity dates i.e. `from_date` and `to_date`. I am trying to find the **applicable price** on a particular date `ref_date`.

Comment: @user12379095 why are you using it then as the key of a keyword argument in `.filter()`? Maybe you want to do: `PriceItems.objects.filter(from_date__lte=ref_date, to_date__gte=ref_date)`? You should really first consult the docs on how to use queryset methods first. You seem to have many misconceptions about that.

Comment: @user12379095 That would simply be: `PriceItems.objects.filter(from_date__lte=ref_date, to_date__gte=ref_date)` assuming that `from_date` and `to_date` are model fields and `ref_date` is a local variable holding a `datetime` object (or maybe a `datetime.date`). In words that means "filter my price items to only include items where the from date is before my ref date and the to date is after my ref date" (Which means that the ref date is between those two).

Comment: Correct. You've been a great help. No words of thanks is enough. And, man you sure do have patience. Thanks again.

Comment: @trixn Not to spoil the feel good env, but you know what. I had just used **Q** objects successfully where the field positioning was exactly as I ended up doing here in this case. In my attempt at making things simpler (less of codes and more of czhutpah) I landed myself in a mess. Not to talk of lost time. Talk about providence. Thanks again.

Comment: @user12379095 A natural part of programming. You will always run into those curfuffles but hopefully be able to avoid this specific one next time :). Glad it helped.

Comment: **Kerfuffles**!! No, not really. :)